# @Html.Hidden does not produce id and value correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create a hidden variable with the result of `Url.Action`. Following code does not produce the required result. What need to be corrected to produce the required result?

Present output

```
<input name="/Controller/Action" type="hidden" value="{ Id = hiddenUrl }" />
```

Required output

```
<input id="hiddenUrlName" type="hidden" value="/Controller/Action" />
```

CODE

```
 <div class="loader">
    @Html.Hidden(@Url.Action("Action", "Controller"),new { Id = "hiddenUrl"})
 </div>
```

Comment: You could inspect the overloads of Html.Hidden method before asking this question.

Answer (score 4):

You've got your overloads mixed up. You want this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492181(v=vs.108).aspx

```
@Html.Hidden("hiddenUrlName", Url.Action("Action", "Controller"),
                                                         new { Id = "hiddenUrl"})
```

You also don't need the `@` in the `Url.Action`

Or which is directly equivalent but not using the HTML helpers.

```
<input id="hiddenUrl" name="hiddenUrlName" type="hidden" 
                             value="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" />
```

Comment: We are alomst there.. but the id is repeating Id="hiddenUrl" id="hiddenUrlName". How can we overcome this?

Comment: That should work, id is a HTML attribute, unless for some reason MVc locks this down for hidden's, but I've never heard of this, you could try second option which I will add now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
@Html.Hidden("hiddenUrlName", Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))
```

The output should be like this:

```
<input id="hiddenUrlName" name="hiddenUrlName" type="hidden" value="/Controller/Action" />
```